# Can I tell pylint about a specific param a decorator requires and have it not apply unused-argument?

Tags: pylint, pyinvoke

I use pyinvoke which has a task decorator that works like this:

```
@task
def mycommand(
    # MUST include context param even if its not used
    ctx: Context
):
    # Do stuff, but don't use ctx
```

Even if I don't use `ctx` I must include it for pyinvoke to work correctly. Pylint throws `Unused argument 'ctx' Pylint(W0613:unused-argument)`.

From what I have read in GitHub issues it seems like it would be unreasonable to expect pylint to dig into decorators and figure them all out automatically.

I also don't want to turn off this pylint rule for the entire function.

Is there a way I can tell pylint that if the `@task` decorator is used do not apply the `W0613` rule to the first argument of the function?

Answer (score 1):

When there is code that is too dynamic and impossible to parse for pylint it's possible to create a "brain" i.e. a simpler version that will explain what the code does to astroid (the internal code representation of pylint). Generally this is what a pylint plugin does (for example pylint-django will do it for view function that need `request`, which is similar to your issue with `ctx`). [Here's an example of brain for `signal` directly in astroid](https://github.com/PyCQA/astroid/blob/43dcd47d34345ca21aab8ea8e82d6721a9183bb1/astroid/brain/brain_signal.py#L40) and [the documentation](https://pylint.pycqa.org/projects/astroid/en/v2.5.6/extending.html?highlight=brain#ast-inference-tip-transforms). It's possible that a pylint plugin already exists so you don't have to do this yourself.

Comment: `It's possible that a pylint plugin already exists so you don't have to do this yourself`. You mean a pylint plugin specifically for pyinvoke or something more generic I could configure for my specific situation?

Comment: Well both, if pylint-pyinvoke does not exists yet, anything you do to make pylint better with pyinvoke could become the official pylint-pyinvoke plugin :)